# What is the difference between a continuous and discontinuous complex function visually?

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the difference between a continuous and discontinuous complex function visually?  Can anyone give graphic examples of a continuous complex function vs. a discontinuous one?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The line where the color changes sharply is a discontinuity in the function. A continuous function would smoothly change colors everywhere. This is a plot of $\log(z)$

Comment: Are there other methods?  One more conducive to drawing by hand?

Comment: No, you're talking about high dimensional objects after all.